# DMG image containing Mac OS X 10.6.5 update not recognized

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, updates, dmg-image

I want to update my Mac OS X 10.6.3 and want to use the manual package update (not Software Update) and I am having this problem for two days now. First I downloaded Mac OS X 10.6.5 Combo update and on the first opening it popped up a message saying *"Unable to mount: disk image not recognized".* I thought that somehow the image became corrupt during the download, so I downloaded it again. Same result. And I downloaded again. And again... No use, it still states that the .dmg is not recognized.

Then I tried to update my system from 10.6.3 to 10.6.4 using the same method (package installer). It worked.
And of course I downloaded the 10.6.5 update (*not* the combo package, but the 10.6.4 > 10.6.5 update package)... guess what. Not recognized.

I don't understand how is this possible. Did anyone has the same problem? Please don't advice me to use software update, as I need to do that on multiple Macs

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the disk image file size and SHA1 has (listed on the [Apple download page](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1324) to make sure it's intact?  Here's what I get on my copy (my hash matches what Apple gives):

```
$ wc -c MacOSXUpdCombo10.6.5.dmg 
 1024680576 MacOSXUpdCombo10.6.5.dmg
$ openssl sha1 MacOSXUpdCombo10.6.5.dmg 
SHA1(MacOSXUpdCombo10.6.5.dmg)= add336a1af1c3914887d2217fbbc98b18e6fb57c
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this behaviour repeat itself on multiple Macs or just the one? If it's just the one, I'd run the Software Update on that one only.

You could also have a file system error. I'd recommend running a drive repair under the Disk Utility to make sure everything's okay.

Comment: I did everything these two days: Disk Utility (Repair disk, Repair disk permissions), booting under safe-mode etc... The behaviour is the same on all Macs. I did my homework too (searching forums, reading discussions).
All other .dmgs are opening, except for this particular one 10.6.5 update

Comment: Then the download is corrupt. Check what @Gordon has written to confirm that it's complete.